# Filter for location including query in nginx

Tags: nginx

This is a super ugly workaround due to a specific customer request.

Default setup: using proxy_pass to the backend like so (i've removed useless items)

```
server{
  server_name customer.mysite.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend.mysite.com/[customerId];
  }
}
```

So far so easy, everything gets rewritten and we are fine. However, now the requirement is that if the customer comes without any query parameters, we should add some.

- https://customer.mysite.com/ -> redirect to https://customer.mysite.com/?query=foo
- https://customer.mysite.com/?query=foo -> apply regular rule

My initial thought was using a second rule with `location = /` for an exact match, but the docs do not indicate that this method cares about query params at all.

So, is there some way to do what I need in nginx or do I have to find some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test for the absence of a query string, you can compare the `$args` variable with an empty string using an `if` block. To apply this rule to the URI `/` only, place it inside a `location = /` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend.example.com/customerId/;
}
location = / {
    if ($args = "") { rewrite ^ /?query=foo last; }
    proxy_pass http://backend.example.com/customerId/;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.